# How to resolve PIP exception from Proxy issues

Tags: python, exception, pip

Just moved to a new work computer and I seem to be getting the following error when I try to use pip. Wondering what the issue could be, python 3.7.2 on Windows 10.

Is it that my work password has characters that aren't allowed?
Strange because my older computer didn't have this issue.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 199, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    skip_reason = self._check_skip_installed(req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 170, in _check_skip_installed
    self.finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 572, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 530, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 675, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 793, in _get_page
    return _get_html_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 144, in _get_html_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 525, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 396, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 410, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 308, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 191, in proxy_manager_for
    proxy_headers = self.proxy_headers(proxy)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 389, in proxy_headers
    password)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\auth.py", line 63, in _basic_auth_str
    password = password.encode('latin1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201d' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops I think I resolved it minutes later. The instructions for the environmental variable for the proxy server password included a "" that wasn't supposed to actually be in the environmental variable text.